# Count Number of Revisions for a Wordpress Post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, revisions

I would like to display the number of revisions for a specific Wordpress post. For example, if  the post ID "78" was updated 8 times, I would like to echo the number "8" in PHP.

Comment: it's better if you also could attach your code attempt here..

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => 78, // id
    'post_type' => 'revision',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$query = get_children($args);
echo count($query); // i.e. 7
```